# Call Jupyter docker from another docker nodejs container

Tags: node.js, docker, jupyter-lab

I have a running docker container with Jupyter lab ("jupyter/minimal-notebook" as base image).

Another docker container server that should be call Jupyter lab passing it the name of notebook to be execute.

Is provided the Jupyter lab server for REST API to call/exec/write/delete/etc notebooks ?